# How should I write my function to fill my structs with groceries in C?

Tags: c, function, struct, fgets

I am currently working on a project where I have one struct named GroceryItem which contains information about the specific grocery.

```
struct GroceryItem {
   char productName[MAX];
   float amount;
   char unit[MAX]; };
```

The second struct should be able to contain 5 different items like this:

```
 struct ShoppingList {
   struct GroceryItem itemList[5];
   int length; };
```

The problem is that I can't seem to fill up the itemList[] using this function

```
void addItem(struct ShoppingList *list)
{
int i = 0;
struct ShoppingList temp;

for (i = 0; i <=4; i++)
{  
    printf("Add an item: \n");
    while (getchar() != '\n');
    fgets(list->itemList[i].productName, MAX, stdin);


}

}
```

What am I doing wrong here? The only spot that gets filled is itemList[0] but nothing happens to the other ones.

Comment: the while loop `while (getchar() != '\n');` is too much!

Comment: Can you show the **addItem** function call?

Comment: @CGi03 The addItem function call looks like this `addItem(&shoppingList)` which should store it in `struct ShoppingList shoppingList;`

Answer (score 0):

It's always better to post compilable code to get accurate answers. (The while loop is not useful and harmful).
If I reduce your code to your problem it gives:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define MAX 32

struct GroceryItem
{
    char productName[MAX];
};

struct ShoppingList
{
    struct GroceryItem itemList[5];
};

void addItem(struct ShoppingList *list)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <5; i++)
    {
        printf("Add an item: \n");
        fgets(list->itemList[i].productName, MAX, stdin);
        list->itemList[i].productName[strcspn(list->itemList[i].productName, "\n")] = '\0';
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    struct ShoppingList shoppingList;
    addItem(&shoppingList);

    puts("Print List:");
    for (int i = 0; i <5; i++)
        puts(shoppingList.itemList[i].productName);

    return 0;
}
```

The line after the fgets is to remove the remaining '\n'.

Comment: For some reason "Add an item: " gets printed out 2 times before I can type anything in. Afterwards it only lets me add 4 items. Do you know why that happens?

Comment: with what code? Modify your question with compilable code.